# Flutter: How to have a Drawer in a Scaffold but no hamburger Icon?

Tags: flutter

I want a Drawer but I want it to be only activated by a hamburger icon located in a BottomAppBar so the icon beside the title of the AppBar is not necessary (I would end up having two icons for the same thing).

It is weird because of the Scaffold automatically adds the hamburger icon if a Drawer is present but the Scaffold (or the Drawer) presents no option to add the icon or not (or which icon to be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind. I just found the parameter. It is in the AppBar:

```
Scaffold(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
);
```

That should get rid of the hamburger icon